# Jquery calculation on Ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have several inputs and what I want to do is calculate them on real time, so for example if you change the **per_day** input depending on that input all other should calculate dynamically , also if I change the **per_year** input all other should take the value depending on the value of that input, and It works fine till I get the ajax request, on success I set the value of 4 inputs and based on that four other inputs should take the value depending on these four but it sets only these four inputs and calculation doesn't work.

```
<input id="per_hour" placeholder="per_hour" class="empCosts" type="number">
<input id="hour" placeholder="hour" class="empCosts" type="number">
<input id="per_day" placeholder="per_day" class="empCosts" type="number">
<input id="day" placeholder="day" class="empCosts" type="number">
<input id="per_month" placeholder="per_month" class="empCosts" type="number">
<input id="months" placeholder="months" class="empCosts" type="number">
<input id="per_year" placeholder="per_year" class="empCosts" type="number">
```

and I calculate them like this

```
function updateCosts(id) {
    var perHour = parseInt($('#per_hour').val());
    var hours = parseInt($('#hour').val());
    var perDay = parseInt($('#per_day').val());
    var days = parseInt($('#day').val());
    var perMonth = parseInt($('#per_month').val());
    var month = parseInt($('#months').val());
    var perYear = parseInt($('#per_year').val());
    var perdayVal = perHour * hours;
    var perMonthVal = perDay * days;
    var perYearVal = perMonth * month;
    var perHourVal = perDay / hours;

    if(id === 'per_day') {

        $("#per_hour").val(Math.ceil(perHourVal));
    }
    else if(id === 'per_month'){
        perdayVal = Math.ceil(perMonth / days);
        $("#per_hour").val(Math.ceil(perHourVal));
    }
    else if(id === 'per_year'){
        perMonthVal = Math.ceil(perYear / month);
        perdayVal = Math.ceil(perMonth / days);
        $("#per_hour").val(Math.ceil(perHourVal));
    }

    id !== "per_day" && $("#per_day").val(perdayVal);
    id !== "per_month" && $("#per_month").val(perMonthVal);
    id !== "per_year" && $("#per_year").val(perYearVal);

}
```

and this to wok on real time i call it like this

```
$('.empCosts').on('input', function () {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        updateCosts(id);
    });
```

this is my ajax

```
$.ajax({
            url:"/red/satu",
            type: "GET",
            data: {user: user},
            success: function (data) {
                $('#per_hour').val(fer.pay.per_hour);
                $("#hour").val(fer.pay.hours);
                $('#day').val(fer.pay.days);
                $("#months").val(fer.pay.months);
                updateCosts("per_day");

            }

        });
```

and on ajax success if I call the function **updateCosts("per_day")** 3 times it works , with one time it doesn't, why is this so? Ajax is loaded first just for info

Comment: Any console errors?

Comment: no there is no error on console, that is why I am confused

Comment: Where is the Ajax called. Right now your code shows it floating around somewhere and calling updatecosts from success AND from event handler

Comment: sorry for my mistake, Ajax is loaded when one of my tabs is selected , thats why I didn't wrote

Comment: Are you waiting for document ready?

Comment: my function updateCosts is outside the` $(function () {})`tag, others are all inside

Comment: as i can see you are calling updateCosts("per_day") this method one time does it is working for one or not?

Comment: Doesn't look like calling `updateCosts("per_day")` would do anything useful there because it appears that `updateCosts()` is supposed to be called with the id of the control that was set (which would be `per_hour` in that case). However, I can see that `updateCosts("per_hour");` exhibits the behavior where it only calculates `per_day` the first time through, and calculates all 3 of the others if called 3 times. The reason for this is that the calculations are producing invalid values the first two times through and setting the inputs to `NaN`.

Comment: `I set the value of 4 inputs and based on that four other inputs should take the value depending on these four but it sets only these four inputs and calculation doesn't work.` , which four inputs are you setting the value for and which 4 inputs are you should have their values changed depending on the first 4 ?

Comment: With one time doesn't work, these inputs are coming from ajax , per_hour,hour,day,months, and depend on this others should automatically calculate

Comment: @JLRishe and what do you suggest me to do in this case, please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is that your calculation logic isn't well thought out. The first time `updateCosts()` is called, it calculates the per day value correctly, but the  per month and per year calculations are based on blank values and therefore evaluate to `NaN`. That's why you have to call it 3 times in order for the values to stabilize. Then you have a few haphazard calculations after that which you carry out based on which field was modified, and they probably recalculate some of the fields correctly, but not all of them.

A better strategy is to pick one per-N value as the baseline, determine the new value for that based on whichever field was modified, and then use that as the starting point for the rest of the calculations.

The following appears to work:

```js
function updateCosts(id) {
  var perHour = parseInt($('#per_hour').val());
  var hours = parseInt($('#hour').val());
  var perDay = parseInt($('#per_day').val());
  var days = parseInt($('#day').val());
  var perMonth = parseInt($('#per_month').val());
  var month = parseInt($('#months').val());
  var perYear = parseInt($('#per_year').val());

  var perHourVal;
  if (id === 'per_day') {
    perHourVal = perDay / hours;
  } else if (id === 'per_month') {
    perHourVal = perMonth / days / hours;
  } else if (id === 'per_year') {
    perHourVal = perYear / month / days / hours;
  } else {
    perHourVal = perHour;
  }

  var perDayVal = perHourVal * hours;
  var perMonthVal = perDayVal * days;
  var perYearVal = perMonthVal * month;

  $("#per_hour").val(perHourVal);
  $("#per_day").val(perDayVal);
  $("#per_month").val(perMonthVal);
  $("#per_year").val(perYearVal);
}

$('.empCosts').on('input', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  updateCosts(id);
});

$('#per_hour').val(12);
$("#hour").val(5);
$('#day').val(7);
$("#months").val(9);

updateCosts('per_hour');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class='empCosts'>
  <tr>
    <td>Per Hour</td>
    <td>
      <input id="per_hour" placeholder="per_hour" class="empCosts" type="number">
    </td>
    <td>Hours</td>
    <td>
      <input id="hour" placeholder="hour" class="empCosts" type="number"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Per Day></td>
    <td>
      <input id="per_day" placeholder="per_day" class="empCosts" type="number"></td>
    <td>Days</td>
    <td>
      <input id="day" placeholder="day" class="empCosts" type="number"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Per Month</td>
    <td>
      <input id="per_month" placeholder="per_month" class="empCosts" type="number"></td>
    <td>Months</td>
    <td>
      <input id="months" placeholder="months" class="empCosts" type="number"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Per Year</td>
    <td>
      <input id="per_year" placeholder="per_year" class="empCosts" type="number"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  </div>
```

As a side note, please don't do this as a half-a**ed way of writing an `if` statement:

```
id !== "per_day" && $("#per_day").val(perdayVal);
```

JavaScript has a syntactical construct for conditionally executing code. It's called an `if`-statement.

Comment: and where do you call the newPerHour function?

Comment: @AndrewJohnson I had initially intended to use that `newPerHour` function but then realized I'd have to pass all 7 values into it in order for it to work. I've deleted it now.

Comment: thank you very mutch there is one more thing i dont understand, my ajax request is called first, so how to get values now

Comment: @AndrewJohnson I don't understand what you're asking. Just use it like you're already using it, but have it call `updateCosts('per_hour');`, not `updateCosts('per_day');`

Answer (score 0):

How about keyup events?

```js
$( "#input_source" )
  .keyup(function() {
    var source_value = $( this ).val();

    //Perform calculations here!!!

    $( "#input_target" ).val( source_value );
  })
  .keyup();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
input_source:
<br>
<input id="input_source" type="text" placeholder="type here" value="">
<br>
input_target:
<br>
<input id="input_target" type="text" placeholder="" value="">
</form>
```

Comment: I don't need keyup , this doesn't help, but thanks anyway